# How can I rename values in a dictionary with a corresponding key value?

Tags: python, list

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
  '6690_team': [6620, 6689], 
  '6620_mdas': [6192, 6573], 
  '6573_megan': [6535, 6572], 
  '6572_regionalise national league north': [6567, 6570], 
  '6570_sacha baron cohen': [6551, 6569], 
  '6569_sacha baron cohen': [6380, 6568], 
  '6568_first week': [6555, 6566]
}
```

How can I rename values with the name of the corresponding key?
For example, the key `6690_team` has two values: `6620` and `6689`.
But `6620_mdas` is also key with the prefix `6620`, so I want to rename the value (`6620` in the `6690_team` key's array) of first key  that has that value as a prefix.

So it would turn into:

```
{
  '6690_team': [6620_mdas, 6689]
}
```

This would happen for the other keys, so the final dictionary would look like:

```
{
  '6690_team': ['6620_mdas', '6569_sacha baron cohen'], 
  '6620_mdas': [6192, '6573_megan'], 
  '6573_megan': [6535, '6572_regionalise national league north'], 
  '6572_regionalise national league north': [6567, '6570_sacha baron cohen'], 
  '6570_sacha baron cohen': [6551, '6569_sacha baron cohen'], 
  '6569_sacha baron cohen': [6380, '6568_first week'], 
  '6568_first week': [6555, 6566]
}
```

Comment: Please update your question with the required output.

Comment: @Man24 I inputted what it looked like you're asking for, double check that that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
dct = {
    "6690_team": [6620, 6689],
    "6620_mdas": [6192, 6573],
    "6573_megan": [6535, 6572],
    "6572_regionalise national league north": [6567, 6570],
    "6570_sacha baron cohen": [6551, 6569],
    "6569_sacha baron cohen": [6380, 6568],
    "6568_first week": [6555, 6566],
}

tmp = {int(k.split("_")[0]): k for k in dct}

for v in dct.values():
    v[:] = [tmp.get(i, i) for i in v]

print(dct)
```

Prints:

```py
{
    "6690_team": ["6620_mdas", 6689],
    "6620_mdas": [6192, "6573_megan"],
    "6573_megan": [6535, "6572_regionalise national league north"],
    "6572_regionalise national league north": [6567, "6570_sacha baron cohen"],
    "6570_sacha baron cohen": [6551, "6569_sacha baron cohen"],
    "6569_sacha baron cohen": [6380, "6568_first week"],
    "6568_first week": [6555, 6566],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to first create a 'reverse lookup' dictionary.

```
dx = {
  '6690_team': [6620, 6689], 
  '6620_mdas': [6192, 6573], 
  '6573_megan': [6535, 6572], 
  '6572_regionalise national league north': [6567, 6570], 
  '6570_sacha baron cohen': [6551, 6569], 
  '6569_sacha baron cohen': [6380, 6568], 
  '6568_first week': [6555, 6566]
}

reverse_lookup_dx = {int(i.split("_")[0]): i for i in dx.keys()}
```

This is a bit dense, but what it does is:

- For each element (i) in the original dictionary's keys...
- Take that element and `split` it on the character `_`...

  - For `6690_team` a `split("_")` will result in `['6690', 'team']
- Then take the first element in the resultant split array.

  - For the previous example, this will yield the string `'6690'`
- Then cast that value to an int.

  - The string `'6690'` becomes the int `6690`.
- Then use a dictionary comprehension to create a 'key' of type int that points to a value of type string (the original key). In this way you can take a value and look it up to see what key it corresponds to - a reverse lookup.

Then it becomes a trivial walk through your dictionary:

```
final_dx = { key: 
  [reverse_lookup_dx.get(item, item) for item in values] 
  for key, values in dx.items()
}
```

This leads to the result :

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(final_dx)
{'6568_first week': [6555, 6566],
 '6569_sacha baron cohen': [6380, '6568_first week'],
 '6570_sacha baron cohen': [6551, '6569_sacha baron cohen'],
 '6572_regionalise national league north': [6567, '6570_sacha baron cohen'],
 '6573_megan': [6535, '6572_regionalise national league north'],
 '6620_mdas': [6192, '6573_megan'],
 '6690_team': ['6620_mdas', 6689]}
```

The `final_dx` stanza combines both a dictionary and a list comprehension. What we are doing is re-creating the dictionary by iterating through each item in the dictionary (`for key, values in dx.items`).

- For each dictionary item...
- Keep the same key...
- Iterate through the value list... (`[... for item in values]`)
- For each item, look it up in the reverse dictionary (`reverse_lookup_dx.get(item, ...)`)
- If it's found, use the result. If it's not use the default provided - in this case `item`. The `get()` function lets you define a default - if you don't find the value in the dictionary, it will return the default instead. So `get(item, item)` will look up the item in the dictionary, return the value at the corresponding key if it exists... otherwise just returns your original value.